# Sub module that points to a single file in the same repo

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

So I want to link a single README.md to a README.md deeper on in the file structure, I've looked into submodules but I haven't seen A way to link just one singular file that is in the same repo. So far it just creates another folder called README.md with the whole repo in it which is not what I want. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "link fileB to fileA" ? if you want to put an html link to fileB in fileA, you just have to mention the correct path in fileA

Comment: Not like link, like link to a page, like link them together.

Comment: Git does not support hard links, but does support symbolic links. Your OS must provide symbolic links, though. Submodules are not this kind of link: they're always a gitlink to a specific *commit* in some repository (normally a different repository, but you can link to the same repository in which the gitlink resides, that's just normally not useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons pointed out by @torek, a Git submodule is not the right tool for your task, but creating and committing a simple symbolic link within your repository will do what you want.

Assume I have an existing repository file `doc/README.md`, and I want to add a `README.md` at the top level of the repository which should always be identical to `doc/README.md`. This is exactly what filesystem symbolic links are for. You create a link: `README.md`, which looks like a file, but is just a reference to another file: `doc/README.md`. Git understands symbolic links and can keep them within a repository.

To create the symbolic link on a Unix-based system:

```
ln -s doc/README.md README.md
```

or on a Windows system:

```
mklink README.md doc\README.md
```

Add the link to your repository:

```
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README.md -> doc/README.md link"
```